# Packages can help to refine parallel mesh and optimize parallel mesh

Tags: mesh

I have a parallel code. The code is implemented using MPI.

I want to find a package that can help to implement global mesh refine and optimize meshes (avoid very thin element).

The mesh in my work is all organized by triangle or tetrahedra.

Do you have any state of art packages for suggestions?

I know the metis/parmetis can be used in graph partition and load balance.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LibMesh](https://libmesh.github.io) supports triangles and tetrahedra as well as quads and hexes.